# Do we still need extern variables since C++17?

Tags: c++, global-variables, c++17, extern

Before C++17 we needed to mark a variable as `extern` to share it among different translation units. We would need to provide an explicit definition of the variable in one translation unit in this case:

```
// common.h
extern const std::vector<int> g_numbers;


// a.cpp
#include "common.h"

const std::vector<int> g_numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };

void a() { /* use g_numbers */ }


// b.cpp
#include "common.h"

void b() { /* use g_numbers */ }
```

But since C++17 we can declare the variable `inline`, and the linker will handle the definition of the variable for us:

```
// common.h
inline const std::vector<int> g_numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };


// a.cpp
#include "common.h"

void a() { /* use g_numbers */ }


// b.cpp
#include "common.h"

void b() { /* use g_numbers */ }
```

Given the fact this is a more convenient and straight-forward way to define a shared variable, I wonder is there still a place for `extern` variables in C++17?

Comment: sort of... i sometimes have global (shared) variables that take 200 lines to declare. i'd rather that not be in a header file. but for simple one-liners, I don't see a reason not to

Comment: Please give code examples for what you think are the ways of using `extern` which can be replaced by `inline` and how. That will help avoid assumptions made by the answerers, i.e. that you might have missed uses of `extern`.

Comment: *"Before C++17 we needed to mark a variable as extern to share it among different translation units."* - no, we did not. There are no use cases for `extern` variables even in plain C. It can be always replaced with a static variable and a getter or with pre C++17 `inline` surrogate. I think at this point `extern` variables are a good target for deprecation and later removal.

Comment: @VTT The question is not about static+getter vs. shared. Let's assume we don't want a getter and want to use the variable directly for whatever reason.

Comment: @Mikhail Then the answer could be "we still need extern variables for whatever reason". Also first and second snippets are not equivalent. Also note that it was possible to declare and define variable in header files without causing linker errors prior to C++17's `inline` so properly equivalent first snippet could be written without using `extern` variable.

Comment: `extern` is an outdated key used for `C`, which shouldn't continue its life in further `C++.xx`. Hey, yo `extern`, get lost, now I can wrap up my code with `namespace` or `class` to trim my body weight better.